# AWS Amplify doesn't forward headers

Tags: request-headers, aws-amplify, http-accept-language

I did deploy a nextjs application on aws amplify, everything is working well.

Now I wanted to use the accept-language header in my application, which does work when I call the cloudfront distribution domain(d2a2q*****apzh.cloudfront.net), but when I call the main link in amplify(https://main.d2u3plsd*****0.amplifyapp.com/), the accept-language header doesn't get forwarded.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Tom! Can you resolve this issue? I've got the same

Answer (score 1):

Amplify uses Cloudfront in background. Cloudfront plays with your headers for few reasons related to caching.

You can refer that list of headers [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior)

I had created [an issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/2316) with Amplify for similar case with ACCEPT, CONTENT_TYPE, HTTP_ACCEPT. Its still in their feature requests.